# Changes in Membership within date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As a newbie I was not sure how to post this and whether it is even suitable as a post. If not I apologize. I have been posed the following question. I tried my best with the tables, please advise if I did it wrong.

| Account | Member | Membership_type | Start_Date | End_Date | Status | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1001 | Premium | 01/01/2022 | 05/31/2022 | Terminated | 2022 |
| 100 | 1001 | Basic | 06/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | Active | 2022 |
| 200 | 2001 | Premium | 01/01/2022 | 03/31/2022 | Terminated | 2022 |
| 200 | 2001 | Premium | 01/02/2022 | 12/31/2022 | Active | 2022 |
| 300 | 3001 | Basic | 01/01/2022 | 02/28/2022 | Terminated | 2022 |
| 300 | 3001 | Basic | 04/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | Active | 2022 |

Question:
From the above table, Member 1001 had a premium plan that ran from 01/01/2022 to 05/31/2022, and then the plan was terminated. In June they switched to a basic plan and would be active from June to Dec 2022. The consumer would have an Active and terminated count in the month of June due to the different plans. Member 2001 has two rows under the same plan, there was an issue with their membership and they terminated in April. Their membership was fixed under the same Membership type to show a correct start and end date range of 01/01/2022 thru to 12/31/2022. The row with the error should not be reported in the output. Member 3001 is similar to 1001 but there is a gap in the membership before they pick up the membership again.

Any ideas on how could achieve the output below from the table above.? I have shortened the output but it should show the status for the members each month unless their last action is to terminate their membership. In which case, it would show the termination month and no further reporting would occur for that member.

| Member | Membership_Type | Status | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Premium | Active | Jan | 2022 |
| 1001 | Premium | Active | .... | 2022 |
| 1001 | Premium | Terminated | June | 2022 |
| 1001 | Basic | Active | June | 2022 |
| 1001 | Basic | Active | .... | 2022 |
| 1001 | Basic | Active | Dec | 2022 |
| 2001 | Premium | Active | Jan | 2022 |
| 2001 | Premium | Active | .... | 2022 |
| 2001 | Premium | Active | Dec | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Active | Jan | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Active | Feb | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Terminated | Mar | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Active | Apr | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Active | .... | 2022 |
| 3001 | Basic | Active | Dec | 2022 |

Comment: What is the question you want to ask, I'm not sure I see it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I’m trying to get the an output from the data in the table at the top to match something like the table at the bottom representing the changes in membership type from month to month.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to generate a calendar table, with a row for each month in the range.

With that done, members `1001` and `3001` work with a simple `JOIN`. The trick is the double/corrected record for member `2001`. We solve that by instead using a LATERAL JOIN/`CROSS APPLY` from the generated calendar data to your original table, where you take the TOP 1 best record that matches for each calendar month. In this way, Member `2001` can match the active plan in March and April, rather than the terminated plan, and show the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance on this Joel, I really appreciate your feedback. I will give this a go. What about where the termination occurs for member 1001 and 3001 being the following month after the last day of active membership? Hopefully that makes sense